# iOS:Code Sign error,Certificate identity appears more than once in the keychain

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcode4.4

I've got stuck in this error ->

> " Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer:XXXXX' appears more than once
>   in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one".

I've removed the old certificate and build a new one,but i am still getting this error again and again.I dont see any duplicated certificate.Please suggest any way to resolve this.
Suggestions will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting your machine. I had this happen to me once a long time ago and if I recall, restarting the machine reinitialized my keychain so it then only saw one cert.

Comment: I had to restart. Once the machine booted back up, I was able to see the duplicate entry and delete it.